# Is asking "was the typo in the headline on this picture of a news site genuinely made" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, scope

There is a picture circulating on social media of a BBC headline from 2017 about a major UK political figure with an unfortunate typo: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Es5oYlpWMAYbvLg.jpg. I want to ask whether that typo was made and quickly corrected by the BBC (or put differently, whether that picture was digitally faked). Is that on-topic?

Comment: The q is interesting, but given the fleeting nature of the evidence, I'm unsure it can be reasonably answered to Skeptics evidence standards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [help center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says, Skeptics is all about challenging notable claims.

If someone came across an image of a headline like that, then there are a number of questions I could imagine a person would have:

- Is/was this a real headline?
- Is what the headline saying true?
- Was this a typo, or was the wording intentional?

Any of those questions could be on-topic here, however just posting the image and asking the question isn't enough. What they'd also need is to show that people are claiming that it's a real headline, and that this claim is widely believed.

So, if you ask your question and also link (for example) a well-known person/site presenting it as true, or show that there are widely shared/viewed posts treating it as though it's true, then your question should be on-topic.

I saw that [one of your other questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/49772/did-the-cnn-live-election-analysis-show-a-porn-site-logo-during-broadcast) also asked whether the content of an image was real, and as part of that question you linked a tweet that appeared to have been widely viewed/liked/retweeted/etc. That's exactly the sort of thing that easily meets the notability requirements, so if you can find something similar for this headline then you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: I see. https://twitter.com/GraystonThe/status/1355135322225577986 is the original tweet I got the image from. Does that tweet have enough likes/RTs to be considered notable? oh wait, there's also this tweet: https://twitter.com/ClaireHammond/status/823100058304397312

Comment: @Nzall: There's no hard rule about how many likes/RTs/views/whatever is considered notable. A few dozen or hundreds is probably not enough, a couple thousand like that first tweet would probably be fine, but if it's in the 10's of thousands like that second tweet then I doubt anyone would say it's not notable.